# Why does this tail recursive function yield <<loop>> error?

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion

I have a strange `<<loop>>` error with the function below. I present it as is since any attempt to simplify eliminates the error as well.

```
bellmanFord :: (DistanceMap m) => m -> [Edge] -> Maybe m
bellmanFord m edges = loop m 0 (length edges)
  where
    loop dists step size =
      if step > size then
        Nothing
      else
        let newDists = foldl' proc dists edges
        in
          if identical newDists dists then
            Just dists
          else
            loop newDists (step + 1) size

    proc dists (v1, v2, w) =
      let d = get dists v2
          d' = get dists v1 + Only w
      in
        if d' < d then
          assoc dists v2 d'
        else
          dists
```

The whole program is available [here](https://gist.github.com/eldargab/09a1d43fd65614e031de).

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but why are you counting up to `size`?  Why not count down to `0` from `size` and use pattern matching to clean up the definition of `loop`?  Something like `loop dists 0 = Nothing; loop dists n = let newDists = ... in if ... then Just dists else loop newDists $ n - 1`?  You'd at least remove the parameter for what step you're on.

Comment: what's the error text in full?

Comment: If removing stuff from your code makes the error disappear, you should take a closer look at the code that you removed right before the error went away. `<<loop>>` means that you have infinite recursion in one of your functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your gist:

```
instance DistanceMap PotMap where
  get m v = min 0 (get m v)
```

Your definition of `get` is infinitely recursive.

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much and sorry for disturbing.